# alterar tipo de dado ntext para text, SQL Server

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, sql-server, dompdf

Preciso alterar o tipo de dado de um campo que está em "ntext" para "text". O motivo é que estou tendo problema ao puxar do banco esse valor e gerar um PDF com o componente DOMPDF do php.

Ao tentar alterar em linha de comando:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ALTER COLUMN mycolumn text
```

obtenho o seguinte erro:

> [Err] 42000 - [SQL Server]Não é possível alterar a coluna 'mycolumn' para o tipo de dados text

Existe alguma outra forma de alterar o tipo de dado de uma tabela? Ou forçar?

Comment: Que tipo de problema ocorre?  //  Experimentou recuperar o conteúdo da coluna utilizando conversão para `nvarchar(max)` e somente após repassando para a classe DOMPDF?  // Já testou se o mesmo problema não ocorre quando o tipo de dados é `text`?

Comment: Com o tipo "text" não tenho problemas, também não cheguei a pensar em converter o nvarchar(max).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta isso:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD mycolumn2 TEXT

UPDATE mytable SET mycolumn2 = mycolumn

ALTER TABLE mytable DROP column mycolumn 

ALTER TABLE mytable ADD mycolumn TEXT

UPDATE mytable SET mycolumn = mycolumn2

ALTER TABLE mytable DROP COLUMN mycolumn2
```

Comment: Esse não era meu ideal, mas fiz algo parecido, valew.

Comment: As vezes ideal e necessário são coisas diferentes  rsrs.